# LINQ select from table where fieldValue is in another tables list of values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

dbContext

```
class Table1

public string Id1 { get; set; }
public string Field { get; set; }
public string Id2 { get; set; }
public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }

class Table2

public string Id2 { get; set; }
public string Field { get; set; }
```

I need to search all records from `Table1` where `Table1Field` is in the other table list of values.

For example first I select all values which matches this search parameter

```
IQueryable<Table2> listOfvalues = from b in dbContext.Table2 
                                  where b.Field1.Contains(searchParam) 
                                  select b;
result = listOfvalues.ToList();
```

And now I need to write code which returns all fields from `Table1` where Field is in that `listOfValues`.

Comment: Your question is unclear.. Read it 3 times and still not sure. Please edit it to make it clear and please add example data of input/output

Comment: Is it about joining two tables? Getting some values from Table2 for search parameters and then from Table1 which joins with Table2 for output values?

Comment: There is a join between Table1 and Table2 so I need to write a Linq query witch returs all Table1 record there Id2 in Table2 where Table2.Field contains searchparam

Comment: Need more elaboration on your question.. Please clear your question in more simple language...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for all items whose particular field matches another field in your already avialable list . you could do something similar.

```
dbContext.Table1.Where(p => listOfvalues.Any(l => p.Field == l.Field)).ToList();
```

EDIT
Try using Contains

```
   var values = listOfvalues.Select (x => x.Field ).ToList();
   dbContext.Table1.Where(p => values.Contains(p.Field)).ToList();
```

Comment: var result = dbContext.Table1s.AsQuerable(); result = result.Where(t => t.Id2 ...

Comment: I got error: Unable to create a constant value of type 'dbContext.xxxx'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: actually everything is ok with Your code.. but I am not lucky to await a query result because of millions records :( don't know the best way to get data by a shortest time ...

Comment: DeadLock occured :(

Answer (score 2):

As you have a navigation property you just need to load the data.

for example:

```
using(dbContext = dbContext.CreateContext())
{ 
    var foo = ...;
    var results = dbContext.Table1Set.Where(t => t.table2.Field == foo);
}
```

As you are still within the context you can use lazy loading due to your virtual property. 
If you are no longer within the context scope when executing your check then you will have to use eager loading.

```
using(dbContext = dbContext.CreateContext())
{ 
    var setData = dbContext.Table1Set().Include(t => t.Table2);
}

var foo = ...;
var results = setData.Where(t => t.Table2.Field = foo);
```

This can be useful when you load your data set in a different method and return only the `Enumerable` collection.

for more information on loading related entities, this link will help:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
using(dbContext = dbContext.CreateContext())
{ 
    var setData = dbContext.Table1Set().Include(t => t.Table2);
}
```

This will work for your case.

Comment: and what it is Table1Set?

Comment: Table1Set is the table which indicates the name of the table in your database.

Comment: thanks a lot... but in this case I also got a DeadLock :( don't know how to get simple list of records...

Answer (score 0):

Data structure:

Table1

```
class Journal
int JournalId {get; set;}
Date JournalDate {get; set;}
string OwnerId {get; set;}
```

Table2

```
class Event
string EventId {get; set;}
string EventName {get; set;}
```

I found a simple solution but also meet another problem ...

First of all I get that List of values

```
var events = DBContext.Events.Where(o => o.EventName.Contains(searchParam)).AsQueryable();
var values = events.Select(x => x.EventID).ToList();
```

I only know how to put query results to list in foreach cycle. I created now List and put there all values where events in list of values I need

```
JournalList  = new List<Journal>();
 foreach (string eventId in values)
  {
    var results = DBContext.Journals.Where(j => j.eventID.Equals(eventId)).ToList();
 RegJournalList.AddRange(results);
  }

 GroupedList = JournalList.Select(t => new JournalGrouped()
                    {
                        JournalID = t.JournalID,
                        JournalDate = t.JournalDate
                   }).Distinct().ToList();
```

But for me is better me is better to have

```
var journals = DBContext.Journals.AsQuarable();
```

not JournalList. Is there any possibilities to get matching data not in list but like a query, because I need to filter it after that??